# Как в golang вывести json не объектами, а массивом?

Tags: json, golang

Я получаю от сервера json ответ в виде объектов в объекте, а хочу получить в виде объектов в массиве.
Вот такой ответ я получаю

```
{"70":{"Id":70,"Exam_Id":5,"Student_Id":2,"Student_Fio":"Иванов"},"71":{"Id":71,"Exam_Id":5,"Student_Id":3,"Student_Fio":"Петров"}
```

А такой хочу получить

```
[{"Id":70,"Exam_Id":5,"Student_Id":2,"Student_Fio":"Иванов"},{"Id":71,"Exam_Id":5,"Student_Id":3,"Student_Fio":"Петров"}]
```

Вот код, который я написал, и который выводит данные не в том виде,котором хочу

```
type StudentsExam struct{
    Id int
    Exam_Id int 
    Student_Id int    
    Student_Fio string 
}
func getData(Exam_Id int) {
    mapToEncode := make(map[string] StudentsExam)
        for id, stud_exam := range StudentsExamList {
            if stud_exam.Exam_Id == Exam_Id {
                mapToEncode[strconv.Itoa(id)] = stud_exam
            }
        }
        data, err := json.Marshal(mapToEncode)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("error: %v\n", err)
            return
        }
}
```

Как вывести data массивом, а не объектами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так у вас mapToEncode ведь тоже не массив. 
Сделайте его массивом тогда и Json массивом станет.

```
var mapToEncode []StudentsExam
```

Comment: Не работает(( Написал var mapToEncode []StudentsExam mapToEncode[strconv.Itoa(id)] = stud_exam  .И так писал mapToEncode[strconv.Itoa(id)] StudentsExam= stud_exam. Пишет syntax error: unexpected name, expecting semicolon or newline or }    и др.

Comment: Это что-же вы за ересь понаписали то? Вам бы книжку почитать чтоли. Вот эту, очень рекомендую http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/19954705/

Comment: Надо вот так примерно http://play.golang.org/p/9A6nEpTj6l

Comment: Спасибо большое. Та вот пока ж и учусь-пытаюсь объять необъятное. Почитаю